# Substituir/alternar slider1.value() por slider2.value() dentro de uma variável no código e dentro da posição no canvas

Tags: javascript, slider

Gostaria de substituir/alternar o slider que dá valor a uma variável dentro de um objeto. O slider2 deve subsituir e ocupar dentro do código e também no canvas o lugar que antes ocupava o slider1, e vice-versa. Vamos supor:

```
var slider1;
var slider2;

function setup() {
createCanvas (windowWidth, windowHeight);

slider1 = createSlider(0, 255, 125);
slider1.position(100, 100);

slider2 = createSlider(0, 500, 125);
slider2.position(100, 100);
}

function draw(){
background(0);  
translate(width/2, height/2);

stroke(255);
strokeWeight(5);
noFill();
ellipse(50, 50, slider1.value(), slider1.value());
}
```

Eu gostaria de, ao acionar algo como uma função keyPressed ou algo assim, substituir o "slider1.value()" pelo "slider2.value()", ali na ellipse.

Um outro problema é posicionar o slider dentro do canvas.

Ao mesmo tempo que gostaria de substituir slider.value(), preciso substituir também o "slider1.position" pelo "slider2.position", já que um vai ocupar o lugar do outro no canvas.

Tentei fazer algo como criar uma função keyPressed depois do function draw, da seguinte forma:

```
var slider1;
var slider2;
var value;

function setup() {
createCanvas (windowWidth, windowHeight);

slider1 = createSlider(0, 500, 100);
slider2 = createSlider(0, 300, 100); 
}

function draw() {

background(150);
translate(width/2, height/2);

value = slider1.value();
stroke(255);
noFill();
strokeWeight(2);
ellipse(0, 0, value, value);

}   

function keyPressed(){

if (keyCode == DOWN_ARROW) {
value = slider2.value();
slider2.position(100, 100);

} else {

value = slider1.value();
slider1.position(100, 100);
}
}
```

mas não deu muito certo, porque se o slider não for criado já no setup, inicialmente aparece situado fora do canvas, o que não me interessa, porque na real a composição é mais complexa, com vários elementos e botões.

E um outro problema derivado disso é que por final, os dois sliders ficam sobrepostos. Eu gostaria que um sumisse para que o outro aparecesse e vice-versa.

Uma solução provisória para não sobrepor os sliders foi, dentro da condição, jogar um ou outro para fora da tela:

```
var slider1;
var slider2;  
var value = 50;

function setup() {
createCanvas (windowWidth, windowHeight);

slider1 = createSlider(0, 500, 100);
slider1.position(100, 100);

slider2 = createSlider(0, 50, 50);
slider2.position(-300, 100); 
}

function draw() {
background(150);
translate(width/2, height/2);

stroke(255);
noFill();
strokeWeight(2);
ellipse(0, 0, value, value);
}

function keyPressed(){

if (keyCode == 'DOWN_ARROW') {

value = slider2.value();
slider2.position(100, 100);
slider1.position(-300, 100);

} else {

value = slider1.value();
slider2.position(-300, 100);
slider1.position(100, 100);
}
}
```

De toda forma, não está respondendo como o esperado.

Espero ter sido claro o suficiente.
Agradeço a atenção.
Abs e feliz ano-novo!

Comment: Seria interessante colocar na pergunta o código para que se possa reproduzir o problema. Só assim na teoria fica complicado.

Comment: Oi, Sam. Não aparece nenhum código na descrição do problema acima? Coloquei 3 tentativas de solução, mostrando os processos que experimentei, mas que não foram bem sucedidos.

Comment: Cara, eu não testei. Só com esses códigos dá pra reproduzir? Não tem HTML/CSS?

Comment: Ah, entendi. Me desculpe, é que uso p5.js. Então o html faz a chamada da biblioteca p5.js, do arquivo javascript (no caso, o código  acima), e roda. Eu vou subir ele para uma plataforma de visualização e coloco aqui pra você ver. abs.

Comment: Sam, subi o sketch nesse editor do p5.js. É possível alterar o código e visualizar o resultado ao acionar o play. Nessa sketch tentei usar um botão para fazer a troca. Ainda assim, a ideia é a mesma: quando acionar a troca (no caso, apertar o botão), trocar do slider1.value para o slider2.value e vice-versa.

Aqui vai o link -> https://editor.p5js.org/ifafa/sketches/S1e8IJsWN

abs

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma resposta: colocar uma condição boolean junto ao botão, como true/false, e quando o botão é acionado, alterna entre esses dois valores.

```
var slider1;
var slider2;
var valuechange;

function setup() {
createCanvas (windowWidth, windowHeight);

slider1 = createSlider(0, 500, 100);
slider1.position(100, 100);
slider2 = createSlider(0, 30, 30);
slider1.position(100, 100);

button = createButton("change");
button.position(100, 50);
button.mousePressed(change);

valuechange = slider1.value();
}


function draw() {
background(150);
translate(width/2, height/2);

stroke(255);
noFill();
strokeWeight(2);
ellipse(0, 0, valuechange, valuechange); 

if (button == true){ 
valuechange = slider2.value(); 
slider2.position(100,100);
slider1.position(-300, 100);

} else {
valuechange = slider1.value ();
slider1.position(100, 100);
slider2.position(-300, 100);
}
}

function change(){

if (button == true){
button = !true;
} else {
button = true; 
}
}
```

__

se quiser verificar o funcionamento, aqui vai o link -> editor.p5js.org/ifafa/sketches/S1e8IJsWN

obrigado!